# Inequality related to basic number theory.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $0<a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2<\infty$ such that $a_1\leq b_1$ and $a_2\leq b_2$ then  porve or disprove the inequality $\frac{a_1}{a_2}\leq \frac{b_1}{b_2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is false.

The counter example is $9\leq10$ and $3\leq 5$, but $$\dfrac{9}{3}=3\geq \dfrac{10}{5}=2.$$ Disapprove.

Comment: If we take $4 \leq 100$ and $3 \leq 5$ we get $\frac 4 3 \leq \frac {100}{ 5}$

Comment: My answer is the counter example of this question. So this question is false statement.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {a_1}{a_2} \le \frac {b_1}{b_2} \iff$

$a_1*b_2 \le b_1*a_2\iff$

$b_2 \le \frac {b_1*a_2}{a_1}$

We know $a_1 \le a_2$ and $b_1 \le b_2$ but we have absolute no restriction on $b_2$.

Let $a_1 = b_2 =a_2 = 1$ and let $b_2 =$ one hundred bajillion zillion.

That is a counter example.

....

I wonder if you meant the other way around and want to prove:

$\frac {a_1}{b_2} \le \frac {b_1}{a_2}$ for  $a_1 \le b_1$ and $a_2 \le b_2$.

That *is* true.

We have $a_1 \le b_1$ so $\frac {a_1}N \le \frac {b_1}N$ for all positive $N$ and if $a_2 \le b_2$ so $\frac M{a_2} \ge \frac M{b_2}$ for all positive $M$ so

$\frac {a_1}{b_2} \le \frac {b_1}{b_2} \le \frac {b_1}{a_2}$

or

$\frac {a_1}{b_2} \le \frac {a_1}{a_2} \le \frac {b_1}{a_2}$

but we can't compare $\frac {b_1}{b_2}$ and $\frac {a_1}{a_2}$ as we know.

.....

One problem with $\frac {a_1}{a_2} \le \frac {b_1}{b_2}$ is we have $a_1 \le b_1$ but also have $\frac 1{a_2} \ge \frac 1{b_2}$ so

we are in a situation where $0< m \le m'$ and $n' \ge n>0$ and we are being asked whether $mn'$ is bigger or less than $m'n$.  As we can "tweak" how small we want $m$ to be but can also tweak how large we want $n'$ to be, we can't have any reasonable answer.

However if $0 < m \le m'$ and $0< n < n'$ we can *definitely* know that $mn < m'n'$.

.....

And if you try to do what I did in the top you get

$\frac {a_1}{b_2} \le \frac {b_1}{a_2} \iff$

$a_1a_2 \le b_1b_2 \iff$

$a_1 \le \frac {b_1b_2}{a_2}=b_1*\frac {b_2}{a_2}$ (which is true as $\frac {b_2}{a_2} \ge 1$ and $b_1\ge a_1$).

or

$\iff a_2\le \frac {b_1b_2}{a_1} =b_2*\frac {b_1}{a_1}$.

or

$\iff \frac {a_1}{b_1} \le \frac {b_2}{a_2}$ (which is true as  $\frac {a_1}{b_1} \le 1 \le \frac {b_2}{a_2}$)